# Can't send request from postman to my docker spring-boot container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to send request from postman to my backend spring-boot container and I get

"could not send request" message

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=booking
      - MYSQL_USER=dhia
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3308:3306

  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
       - 8091:8091
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/booking
    depends_on:
       - mysqldb
```

The application started fine and 0 errors

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18-slim as MAVEN_BUILD
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
FROM openjdk:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

```
bookingsystem-app-1      |
bookingsystem-app-1      |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
bookingsystem-app-1      |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
bookingsystem-app-1      | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
bookingsystem-app-1      |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
bookingsystem-app-1      |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
bookingsystem-app-1      |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
bookingsystem-app-1      |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)
bookingsystem-app-1      |
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:34.994  INFO 1 --- [           main] Booking.BookingApplication               : Starting BookingApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 18-ea on 521f32647790 with PID 1 (/app/app.jar started by root in /app)
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:35.005  INFO 1 --- [           main] Booking.BookingApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:36.215  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:36.325  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.470  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.499  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.499  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.637  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.638  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2339 ms
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:37.753  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:38.142  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:38.342  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:38.466  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:38.792  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:38.946  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
bookingsystem-app-1      | Hibernate:
bookingsystem-app-1      |
bookingsystem-app-1      |     alter table bookings
bookingsystem-app-1      |        add constraint FK4xjjw8rumqxvr8c6t7xm6q8ty
bookingsystem-app-1      |        foreign key (hike_id)
bookingsystem-app-1      |        references hikes (id)
bookingsystem-app-1      | Hibernate:
bookingsystem-app-1      |
bookingsystem-app-1      |     alter table bookings
bookingsystem-app-1      |        add constraint FKg37gxkbbjvc3dp3een92kxy05
bookingsystem-app-1      |        foreign key (hiker_id)
bookingsystem-app-1      |        references hikers (id)
bookingsystem-app-1      | Hibernate:
bookingsystem-app-1      |
bookingsystem-app-1      |     alter table hikes
bookingsystem-app-1      |        add constraint FKs8qvf1tnml0ahxs407ggng3bs
bookingsystem-app-1      |        foreign key (trail_id)
bookingsystem-app-1      |        references trails (id)
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:39.988  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:40.000  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:40.542  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:41.008  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
bookingsystem-app-1      | 2022-08-21 11:10:41.019  INFO 1 --- [           main] Booking.BookingApplication               : Started BookingApplication in 6.813 seconds (JVM running for 7.789)
```

This is my application properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/booking
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.password=root
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
server.port=8090
```

The problem that I can't access to my controllers or send any requests I tried all the Ports and all the names ( localhost, booking, app ) and always CONNREFUSED

http://mysqldb:8080/hikes

http://mysqldb:8090/hikes

http://mysqldb:8091/hikes

http://localhost:8080/hikes

http://localhost:8090/hikes

http://localhost:8091/hikes

By the way when I run it without the container everything work fine.

Comment: `Tomcat started on port(s): 8090` and in docker-compose `ports: - 8091:8091` 

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these port numbers with the same port number
dockerfile -> EXPOSE 8080 -> EXPOSE 8090
docker-compose.yml -> ports: - 8091:8091 -> ports: - 8090:8090
this will work because your application using 8090 port and you using 8091 to run your application in your docker-compose, and at the same time trying to expose with 8080 port